# Skipping logic app connector

Tags: workflow, azure-logic-apps, connector

Hi i was wondering is there any possibility to skip or disable a logic app connector in a workflow?

I know the triggers sometimes skip a run if there is nothing to trigger the logic app. But is there a similar option regarding the workflow connectors like a checkbox or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES**.  You just need to use a Condition and put the Action (connection oriented or not) in the True part.  You do have to write the check yourself, [count of some array] > 0, or such.

There's no way for an Action to Skip itself and even the Skipped Trigger runs, it just doens't invoke when there's no output.

Answer (score 1):

If the action supports it, you could put the action into testing mode with a static success result.  I use this to bypass email notifications that are only needed for testing.

[Screenshot - Logic Apps Testing Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieKDl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge. You could add a condition in your Logic App definition and execute the connector (and following actions) only when the condition is met. In the false-branch you don't add that connector or set different logic.

You can also have a look at the "Run After"-option, which is where you specify when a connector should be executed, based on the result of the previous action.

Comment: Yeah i did something similar to put a parallell  branch to only run if previous connector is "skipped" (which it is not), which makes the logic app to jump that step. but still. In this case i i don't have any following connectors  connected t run after the step i want to skip. but if i had i would jump those too i guess.